# Restarting Services on multiple Boxes

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I've been getting a handle on Ansible for a couple weeks now. I think it's coming along well. All my work has been 1-to-1 or one Ansible job to one server/process.

What's the best way to handle restarting services on multiple servers?

Ex: I need to restart an app server and database server with slave.

The main issue is I need to maintain a order similar to this:
S1 Stop application
S3 Stop replication
S2 Restart master
S1 Restart application
S3 Start replication

Or am I overthinking this too much?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a pretty straightforward [playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks.html) to me:

```
---
- hosts: s1
  tasks:
    - name: stop application

- hosts: s3
  tasks:
    - name: stop replication

- hosts: s2
  tasks:
    - name: restart master

- hosts: s1
  tasks:
    - name: start application

- hosts: s3
  tasks:
    - name: start replication
```

(You'll need to fill in the task definitions with whatever you actually need to do.)

Playbooks are all about defining a series of steps to take, and they don't have to all be on one set of servers.